# Lazarus IDE forms size

Tags: lazarus

On Ubuntu/Bodhi with two monitors I installed and recompiled Lazarus.
As I found on some forums Bodhi represent two monitors as one, so Lazarus hard-coded and compiled with minimal forms size for two monitors. I disconnected one monitor and now Source code editor, Messages forms are too wide, wider than my monitor and I can't reduce their sizes.
Where and what parameters I need to change to recompile Lazarus for one monitor? Is it something like Constraints.MinHeight/MinWidth? What file?

Comment: I think you would probably do better to ask this q on the Lazarus support forum : https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/ as it would likely reach a wider audience with relevant experience.  Qs about Lazarus on Linux are rather infrequent here on SO.

Comment: actually I confused too, is it Lazarus or Bodhi/E17/Moksha issue, I hope someone else using Lazarus on Bodhi faced the same issue and could clarify,